# Is any API is used to create email id in php?

Tags: php, email

Dear experts, I want to create email id dynamically in my website to send messages. my site is a free messaging system ,which is used to send message in U.S phone numbers.Please give me a solution for these.

Comment: you need to explain more, im struggling to understand what you need exactly.

Comment: Yup. We need more information. Could you give us an example of an "email id"?

Comment: If you are talking about the ID in the mail message headers, just leave this up to whatever library you are using to send mail with.  You're using something more than just `mail()`, right?  Check into Pear's Mail package.  There are also many alternatives.

Comment: "send message in U.S. phone numbers". Sounds like SMS spam to me...

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a database.
2. Create an email table in your database.

To this table:

> 1. Define an ID field in the table that is auto numbered. (Make it a
>      unique primary key).
> 2. Define all of the fields of information you want to remember about
>      your email.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you refer to building an RFC-822 compliant Message-Id field as described by :

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html

```
$fqdn_hostname = "mydomain.com";
$MessageId = "<" . sha1(microtime()) . "@" . $fqdn_hostname . ">";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to send emails from random email ID's ..

copied from php.net

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

you can change the headers as required clubbed with some random string generation function.